# Custom Date Component ( input ) and useRef

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a custom date component for my project which has a label and an Input tag. I'm using Chakra UI as component library. I have used 3 useRef hooks to specify the ref value for date component. When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after user has input the value and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the focus should navigate to next input box, I want the same functionality as tab but using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I'm also wrapping my `DateComponent` in forward ref.

```
const ref1 = useRef(); 
const ref2 = useRef();  
const ref3 = useRef();  

const handleKeyPress = (event) => {   
   if(event.key === 'Enter') ref2.current.focus();  
}  

<Box>  
  <DateComponent ref={ref1} onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}/>  
  <DateComponent ref={ref2} onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}/>  
  <DateComponent ref={ref3} onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}/>  
</Box>
```

This doesn't work for me, as the current value of ref2 is showing null in console.